# number of ordered pairs to get a = c mod 3 and b = d mod 5

Tags: probability, combinatorics

What is the minimum number of ordered pairs of non-negative numbers that
should be chosen to ensure that there are two pairs (a,b) and (c,d) in the chosen
set such that
a = c mod 3 and b = d mod 5. 
This was asked in GATE 2005. Here they haven't mentioned any constraints on the ordered pairs. I don't have any clue how to approach this problem. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an application of the pigeonhole principle. Every pair $(x,y)$ represents a pair of congruence classes in $\def\Z{\Bbb Z}\Z/3\Z \times\Z/5\Z$, and the question is how many pairs must be chosen to ensure that a same pair of congruence classes is attained twice. There are $\#(\Z/3\Z \times\Z/5\Z)=3\times5=15$ different such pairs of congruence classes, and the pigeonhole principle says that in whatever way $16$ pairs $(x,y)$ are chosen, two of them are bound to occupy the same pair of congruence classes. And on the other hand with only $15$ pairs $(x,y)$, it would clearly be possible to occupy every one of the $15$ pairs of congruence classes exactly once.

Comment: I am an absolute beginner in the topic. Can u tell me how to count the congruent classes in a non trivial example.

Comment: For any integer $n>0$ there are $n$ congruence classes modulo$~n$. For instance there are $7$ classes modulo$~7$, namely the classes of $0,1,2,3,4,5,6$: they all lie in distinct classes, and any integer lies in the congruence class of (exactly) one of them. Also for every pair $X,Y$ of finite sets with $n,m$ elements respectively; the Cartesian product $X\times Y$ contains exactly $nm$ pairs $(x,y)$. In particular there are $nm$ pairs $(x,y)$ of congruence classes of integers, $x$ being a class modulo$~n$ and $y$ being a class modulo$~m$. What I said is an instance of this for $n=3$ and $m=5$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now it is really clear. If n and m have common factors among them, then a more precise answer will be the LCM of the two numbers I believe.

Answer (score 1):

We show that $16$ pairs are enough, but $15$ pairs need not be.

If we have $16$ or more pairs, there are at least $6$ pairs whose first entries are congruent to each other modulo $3$.  This is because the first entry of any pair is congruent to one of $0$, $1$, or $2$ modulo $3$. If there were $\le 5$ of each type, then the number of pairs would be $\le (3)(5)=15$.

And since there are at least $6$ such pairs, $2$ of them at least have their second entries congruent modulo $5$.

To show that $15$ pairs are not enough, consider the pairs $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(0,2)$, $(0,3)$, $(0,4)$, and $(1,0)$, $(1,1)$, $(1,2)$, $(1,3)$, $(1,4)$, and $(2,0)$, $(2,1)$, $(2,2)$, $(2,3)$, $(2,4)$.

Comment: There is no real need to apply the pigeonhole principle twice in succession here.

Comment: True, but I thought this was a "more basic" approach.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ By CRT, the map $\,(j,k)\mapsto (j\ {\rm mod}\ 3,\ k\ {\rm mod}\ 5)\,$ is not $1$-$1$ if its domain has size $> 15$

Comment: The CRT has nothing to do with this; it's just about $\def\Z{\Bbb Z}\#(\Z/3\Z \times\Z/5\Z)$.

Comment: @Marc Depends on what one includes under the fuzzy, oft-overloaded moniker "CRT".

Comment: Could be, but all versions I know of include some mention of arithmetic; relative primality, gcd or lcm. In this question the relative primality of $3,5$ is irrelevant; the question with $3,6$ in place of $3,5$ would have an entirely analogous answer, with $3\times6=18$ in the place of $3\times5=15$.

Comment: @Marc Many students at this level have no knowledge of rings, let alone product rings. However, they often do have knowledge of working with pairs of residues (and associated counting arguments) gleaned from presentations of CRT in treatises on elementary number theory. That is what I refer to in the (admittedly terse) "CRT" reference. It seems that you may have interpreted it much more specifically than it was intended.

Comment: The point is not that you are not clear; it is that your hint quite clearly points in the wrong direction. As for me, I think I had already been clear (and you can read my answer to see that this is just a pigeonhole question), but let me say it again, differently. CRT is about representing pairs of residues (mod distinct numbers) as a common residue of a _single_ integer; if you leave that part out there is just nothing left of CRT. However this question is only about pairs of residues, period. You fired too rapidly, and without looking well at the target: the CRT is just a red herring here.

Comment: @Marc Your interpretation isn't what I intended, but that is my fault for being too terse with the overloaded "CRT" terminology. Again, by CRT I did not denote a *specific theorem*. Rather, I denoted the general discussion of this and related topics topics (in typical *elementary* number theory textbooks). We *are* in the same ball park regarding *specific theorems* usually denoted by CRT. But that's not what the term CRT denotes in my answer. Apologies if that confused you. Often I strive to keep my hints to one line. Here that constraint forced too much compromise in precision of denotation.